# PHP - Use one field to create multiple database row entries

Tags: php, forms, post

I am trying to work out the best way of using one form field that can update multiple rows in mysql. My intention is to capture a set of web addresses in one box om a form e.g.

```
http://google.com http://www.bing.com http://www.yahoo.com https://wwwpaypal.com
```

And I would like that to create four entries in my database:

```
http://google.com
http://bing.com
http://www.yahoo.com
https://wwwpaypal.com
```

Is the best way to try and find the spaces and split the post input or is there a better way?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that it is good to put multiple values in one field... But if you want to do so, look for a character which cannot occur in an url

Comment: Is there any reason, why you can not use multiple fields?

Comment: if you don't know exact number of fields, create a button which will crerate new input field. this will be more simple both for you and your users

Comment: Just trying to make it easier for the user, they can put up to twenty urls in, so ideally I dont want to put 20 fields on screen that they may end up using only one of, but I might consider doing that.

Comment: Mantra: *There is always a better way of doing things!* But since spaces afaik aren't allowed in URLs using them to divide your entries in a form box should do the job in the first place.

Comment: technically speaking, spaces can do the job.
but a newline would do a better job with the usability and readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split on the spaces in PHP and just loop to insert them into the database.

```
$entries = explode(' ', $list_of_entries);
foreach ($entries as $entry) {

    // Assuming you need some id column to map entries in `$id_column_value`...
    $entry = mysql_real_escape_string($entry);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES('$id_column_value', '$entry');
}
```

Comment: @k102 assuming some id to map these entries to.  Added as a comment

Answer (score 2):

```
$entries = explode(" ", $_POST['entries']);
foreach ($entries as $entry){
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries ('entry') VALUES ('".mysql_real_escape_string($entry)."');");
}
```

Comment: he did not ask how to do it in php... he asked if it is a good idea

Comment: "Is the best way to try and find the spaces and split the post input or is there a better way?" I'm giving him better way u mad?

Comment: yep, that'S better way to "split" string rather than to give each string to one line

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I would just use

```
$arrayOfAddresss = explode(" ",$formInput);
```

and insert these into the table.